# Is UK Transit Visa required?

Tags: visas, uk, ukrainian-citizens

I am returning to Ukraine from Canada in August, requiring a 1 night layover at Heathrow (I have booked at  Sofitel).  I am British Airway both flights, going through Terminal 5.  Do I need any kind of UK visa to layover (I have Ukrainian passport and a Canadian visitor visa)

Comment: @JoErNanO I can't find anything in this question regarding landside transit and whether or not this applies in the question.

Comment: @Karlson As they need to go landside, the OP will need permission to enter the UK, either as a normal visitor or under a "Visitor in Transit Visa", which the linked question covers both cases of

Comment: @Gagravarr According to [this document](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/364371/hc-693.pdf) section 7.19 *These amendments to the Immigration Rules establish clear requirements to allow visa nationals to transit landside through the UK provided they hold a valid exemption document under the transit without visa scheme* Except I can't find the details on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the relevant page](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/ukraine/transit/yes) from gov.uk

It appears that you may be eligible to transit without a visa, under the grounds that your onward flight is before midnight on the day after you arrive, and presuming you are going direct to Ukraine.

This is the additional criteria you need to meet, note the time criteria:

> You’re travelling from (or on part of a reasonable journey from) Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and it’s less than 6 months since you last entered that country with a valid entry visa

In the case that you are not going direct to Ukraine from Heathrow but visiting another country inbetween, you will also need to show the 'correct documents' for your next destination after Heathrow (i.e. a valid visa if required).